# RSA signature verification given public exponent and modulus

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature

Trying to code signature verification using Sun JCE with test vectors from the CAVP program.

i'm given public key exponent, and modulus, as well as the message and signature.  I do the following:

```
    private static boolean verifySignature(String algo, PrintStream oPS, byte[] message, byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, byte[] sigBytes, int saltlen)  throws Exception
    {
            Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algo);
            KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
                            new BigInteger(modulus),
                            new BigInteger(exponent));

            RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyMaker.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

            System.out.println("algorithm is " + algo);
            sig.initVerify(pubKey);
            Utils.outputValue("n", modulus, modulus.length, System.out, false);
            Utils.outputValue("e", exponent, exponent.length, System.out, false);
            Utils.outputValue("Msg", message, message.length, System.out, false);
            Utils.outputValue("S", sigBytes, sigBytes.length, System.out, false);
            BigInteger Nvalue = pubKey.getPublicExponent();
            Utils.outputValue("key value of n", Nvalue.toByteArray(), System.out, false);
            BigInteger Evalue=pubKey.getModulus();
            Utils.outputValue("key value of e", Evalue.toByteArray(), System.out, false);
            sig.update(message);
            if(sig.verify(sigBytes))
                    oPS.println("Result = P");
            else
                    oPS.println("Result = F");
```

.
.
.

The algo is something like "SHA1withRSA", and i build the public key as shown.  When i list the resulting modulus and exponent from the key itself, they have become reversed.

n = 009de541c71a95389d9e8619ea1d6e2c69ed6c703701e518351676022ab98395d6b35a38b024f92bce6dd1c5be9d51dffd1687d19dceee73f2c73e4436b955231255f6e3e360ba84462311e10e65932fe069bed2d42c5bf2f88141828bdad3796184870cb8cf3019da264e56b39eccf7224d43a1b98d788b40a4042aac790e946f
e = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
Msg = 64b13df4b008ccccd5ce146018481c2568bbe2b93ec658d1c7f4ad734592cd65b3be2be5a7c1be9a7d9f49cbb2ece0cf8ee0a8c406aede84e0121bd51829d6e083862ae5b282d92c19d3923f70616f565a55c2134572116f91a85ff5f4e6ad2e1d31c15c97f3266af19574241c4fd2a4143fb80cc2b9fa7b22df0239a1715c35
S = 5b4458f6aeff91c4699ee9bdf8757987fb8db229814a2992945ac53bcf19b9179e53cfed258726d205107ac000d41e570fe8c4fb321fc9b4b5469c60cd20032195f314ba6e6b0b30a51c9834242daa1ce525ec90380106568e782ea164baeda5d884defe6e720e9dd63618b823412445e17f991a6daa21bd62bdc73d7d8a20e5
key value of n = 03
key value of e = 009de541c71a95389d9e8619ea1d6e2c69ed6c703701e518351676022ab98395d6b35a38b024f92bce6dd1c5be9d51dffd1687d19dceee73f2c73e4436b955231255f6e3e360ba84462311e10e65932fe069bed2d42c5bf2f88141828bdad3796184870cb8cf3019da264e56b39eccf7224d43a1b98d788b40a4042aac790e946f

Some of these tests are supposed to fail, but some should succeed.  None verify correctly...  Any thought?  Thanks.

Application is below, followed by one set of sample input.

```
package cavp.rsa;


import cavp.*;

import java.io.*;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import java.util.Date;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class RSASigVerify
{
        private static boolean verboseFlag=false;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                String requestFile;
                String responseFile;

                int saltLen=-1;
                int argstart=0;

                if(args.length < 2)
                        throw new Exception("missing parameters");
                if(args.length == 3) {
                        if(args[0].equals("-saltlen")) {
                                saltLen=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                                if(saltLen < 0)
                                        throw new Exception("bad -saltlen parameter ");
                                argstart=2;
                        } else {
                                if(args[0].equals("-x931")) {
                                        saltLen=-2;
                                        argstart=1;
                                }
                } else {
                        if(args.length > 3)
                                throw new Exception("invalid invocation");
                }
                requestFile=args[argstart];
                responseFile=args[argstart+1];
                if(processFile(requestFile, responseFile, saltLen))
                        System.out.println("Failed to process file " + requestFile);
                else
                        System.out.println("Processing complete for " + requestFile);
        }

        private static boolean processFile(String rqfn, String rspfn, int saltLen) throws Exception
        {
                File inFile = new File(rqfn), outFile = new File(rspfn);

                if(!inFile.exists() || !inFile.isFile() || !inFile.canRead()) {
                        System.out.println("Bad input File " + rqfn);
                        return true;
                }
                FileReader inFR = new FileReader(inFile);
                BufferedReader inBR = new BufferedReader(inFR);
                PrintStream outPS = new PrintStream(outFile);

                String input, keyword, value, digestType=null;
                int p, v, q, i, lnum=0;
                byte[] Msg=null, nBytes=null, eBytes=null, sigBytes=null;
                boolean msgFound=false, nFound=false, eFound=false, sigFound=false;


                try {
                        while((input = inBR.readLine()) != null ) {
                                lnum++;
                                if((p = input.indexOf('=')) < 0) {
                                        outPS.println(input);
                                        continue;
                                }
                                if(input.charAt(p-1) == ' ')
                                        keyword=input.substring(0,p-1);
                                else
                                        keyword=input.substring(0, p);
                                p++;
                                for(i=p; i<input.length(); i++) {
                                        if(input.charAt(i) == ' ')
                                                p++;
                                        else
                                                break;
                                }
                                if((v = input.indexOf('\n')) > 0) {
                                        for(q=v-1; q>p+1; q--) {
                                                if(input.charAt(q) != ' ')
                                                        break;
                                        }
                                } else {
                                        if((v = input.indexOf(' ', p)) > 0) {
                                                q=v-1;
                                        } else {
                                                q=input.length();
                                        }
                                }

                                value=input.substring(p,q);
                                if(keyword.indexOf("n") >= 0) {
                                        nBytes=Utils.hexStringToByteArray(value);
                                        if(nBytes.length <= 0) {
                                                System.out.println("bad value for modulus");
                                                return true;
                                        }
                                        nFound=true;
                                } else {
                                        if(keyword.equals("e")) {
                                                eBytes=Utils.hexStringToByteArray(value);
                                                if(eBytes.length <= 0) {
                                                        System.out.println("bad value for private exponent");
                                                        return true;
                                                }
                                                eFound=true;

                                        } else {
                                                if(keyword.equals("SHAAlg")) {
                                                        if(!value.equals("SHA1") && !value.equals("SHA224") && !value.equals("SHA256") && !value.equals("SHA384") &&
                                                                        !value.equals("SHA512")) {
                                                                System.out.println("Bad SHAAlg parameter " + input);
                                                                return true;
                                                        }
                                                        digestType=value + "withRSA";
                                                } else {
                                                        if(keyword.equals("Msg")) {
                                                                if(msgFound) {
                                                                        System.out.println("more than one Msg found");
                                                                        return true;
                                                                } else
                                                                        msgFound=true;
                                                                String tempMsg;
                                                                if((value.length() & 0x01) != 0)  {
                                                                        tempMsg="0" + value;
                                                                } else {
                                                                        tempMsg=value;
                                                                }
                                                                Msg=Utils.hexStringToByteArray(tempMsg);
                                                                if(Msg.length <= 0) {
                                                                        System.out.println("bad Msg parameter");
                                                                        return true;
                                                                }
                                                        } else {
                                                                if(keyword.equals("S")) {
                                                                        sigBytes=Utils.hexStringToByteArray(value);
                                                                        if(sigBytes.length <= 0) {
                                                                                System.out.println("bad signature parameter");
                                                                                return true;
                                                                        }
                                                                        sigFound=true;
                                                                } else {
                                                                        if(keyword.equals("Result")) {
                                                                                continue;
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }


                                        }
                                }
                                outPS.println(input);
                                if(digestType != null && msgFound && nFound && eFound && sigFound) {
                                        if(verifySignature(digestType, outPS, Msg, nBytes, eBytes, sigBytes, saltLen)) {
                                                throw new Exception("error in digest generator");
                                        }
                                        msgFound=false;
                                        eFound=false;
                                        sigFound=false;
                                }
                        }
                } catch( FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("error processing file");
                }
                inFR.close();
                outPS.close();
                return false;
        }

        private static boolean verifySignature(String algo, PrintStream oPS, byte[] message, byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, byte[] sigBytes, int saltlen)  throws Exception
        {
                // yet to implement saltLen == -2 for X9.31 padding
                //                  saltLen >= 0 for PSS Signatures

                Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algo);
                KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
                                new BigInteger(modulus),
                                new BigInteger(exponent));


                RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyMaker.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

                System.out.println("algorithm is " + algo);
                sig.initVerify(pubKey);
                sig.update(message);
                if(sig.verify(sigBytes))
                        oPS.println("Result = P");
                else
                        oPS.println("Result = F");
                return false;
        }
}
```

The following is one vector from the input:

```
# CAVS 11.5
# "SigVer PKCS#1 Ver 1.5" information for
# Mod sizes selected: 1024 2048
# SHA Algorithm selected:SHA1 SHA256
# Generated on Mon Nov 28 14:03:58 2011
[mod = 1024]
n = 9de541c71a95389d9e8619ea1d6e2c69ed6c703701e518351676022ab98395d6b35a38b024f92bce6dd1c5be9d>51dffd1687d19dceee73f2c73e4436b955231255f6e3e360ba84462311e10e65932fe069bed2d42c5bf2f88141>828bdad3796184870cb8cf3019da264e56b39eccf7224d43a1b98d788b40a4042aac790e946f
SHAAlg = SHA1
e = 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
Msg = 64b13df4b008ccccd5ce146018481c2568bbe2b93ec658d1c7f4ad734592cd65b3be2be5a7c1be9a7d9f49cbb2>ece0cf8ee0a8c406aede84e0121bd51829d6e083862ae5b282d92c19d3923f70616f565a55c2134572116f91a8>5ff5f4e6ad2e1d31c15c97f3266af19574241c4fd2a4143fb80cc2b9fa7b22df0239a1715c35
S = 5b4458f6aeff91c4699ee9bdf8757987fb8db229814a2992945ac53bcf19b9179e53cfed258726d205107ac000>d41e570fe8c4fb321fc9b4b5469c60cd20032195f314ba6e6b0b30a51c9834242daa1ce525ec90380106568e78>2ea164baeda5d884defe6e720e9dd63618b823412445e17f991a6daa21bd62bdc73d7d8a20e5*
```

Here is a vector file which should Pass:

```
# CAVS 11.5
# "SigVer PKCS#1 Ver 1.5" information for 
# Mod sizes selected: 1024 2048
# SHA Algorithm selected:SHA1 SHA256
# Generated on Mon Nov 28 14:03:58 2011

[mod = 1024]

n = 9de541c71a95389d9e8619ea1d6e2c69ed6c703701e518351676022ab98395d6b35a38b024f92bce6dd1c5be9d51dffd1687d19dceee73f2c73e4436b955231255f6e3e360ba84462311e10e65932fe069bed2d42c5bf2f88141828bdad3796184870cb8cf3019da264e56b39eccf7224d43a1b98d788b40a4042aac790e946f

SHAAlg = SHA1
e = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
Msg = fe196459e8232a9f94e8c93d88ddae7d38be7a10e2dd03ffb7bb9be43bd59659eec006b12c78c9e652f6c6d3220073a369459b8adea95eb34ede7979f634c7d931b208275365e201d4f82582b18553b70fab605721e1b6ae4d097cdb8a49183b0d16f22524917bd862176fb1fc1357a2731751df732c13dafc662e72bfbb9067
S = 94af4ce7f323d1bf4904a673d2884e30a55a108c44e4eb2bfc0a0f061f46fefe23fe74c760e947bd1fbf1bb1a30d66b3d7dccfb425d3a6551dd444f90d4f06c3e0da6dc3c7a45e062b08d24553f0091acae47ffaae495e13da66308dd9e0be87e2b960ab823f83e55815b66a1076ab238cc3883cbf7312521d0988214bb07d96
```

Answer (score 3):

I have updated my answer. I was not correct when I said your sample will not work because the signature is as long as the message. In fact, since RSA encryption happens after SHA-1 computation, the final signature can be up-to *n* bytes long where *n* is the size of the modulus `N`.

So, from what I can tell, you may not have a problem at all. Are you sure the sample you posted is a positive case? If so, are you sure it was created using `SHA1withRSA` algorithm?

Below I have included sample, Groovy, code based on your code. The code basically creates a signature and verifies it. I got the public and private key pairs from [this](http://nmichaels.org/rsa.py) site but any key pair will work. The code is self explanitory so I'll just summarize how the signature is supposed to work incase you'd like to test and verify using random key pairs and messages.

1. Compute hashcode **h** on message **m**. In this case is [`h = SHA-1(m)`](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=00).
2. Compute signature **s** on hashcode **h** by signing/encrypting it with private key **d**.
3. Validate signature **s** by verifying/decrypting it with public key **e** and checking the value equals the hashcode of **m**.

As you can see, the steps above can be performed with simple RSA computation tools. I have checked the example provided in my code to be correct. On thing I found interesting is that Java throws a `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Message is larger than modulus` exception if the modulus is negative (1st bit is set in 2's complement) so I had to append 1 byte of zeros to the left.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.*;
import java.security.spec.*;


byte[] modulus = Utils.getBytes("00d94d889e88853dd89769a18015a0a2e6bf82bf356fe14f251fb4f5e2df0d9f9a94a68a30c428b39e3362fb3779a497eceaea37100f264d7fb9fb1a97fbf621133de55fdcb9b1ad0d7a31b379216d79252f5c527b9bc63d83d4ecf4d1d45cbf843e8474babc655e9bb6799cba77a47eafa838296474afc24beb9c825b73ebf549");
byte[] publicExp = Utils.getBytes("010001");
byte[] privateExp = Utils.getBytes("047b9cfde843176b88741d68cf096952e950813151058ce46f2b048791a26e507a1095793c12bae1e09d82213ad9326928cf7c2350acb19c98f19d32d577d666cd7bb8b2b5ba629d25ccf72a5ceb8a8da038906c84dcdb1fe677dffb2c029fd8926318eede1b58272af22bda5c5232be066839398e42f5352df58848adad11a1");
byte[] message = Utils.getBytes("00");
byte[] signature;
signature = createSignature("SHA1withRSA", System.out, message, modulus, privateExp, signature);
println ((new BigInteger(signature)).toString(16));
            verifySignature("SHA1withRSA", System.out, message, modulus, publicExp, signature);


public static boolean verifySignature(String algo, PrintStream oPS, byte[] message, byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, byte[] sigBytes)  throws Exception
{
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algo);
    KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(exponent));
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyMaker.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

    sig.initVerify(pubKey);
    sig.update(message);

    return sig.verify(sigBytes);
}

public static byte[] createSignature(String algo, PrintStream oPS, byte[] message, byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, byte[] sigBytes)  throws Exception
{
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(algo);
    KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPrivateKeySpec privKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus), new BigInteger(exponent));
    RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey)keyMaker.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);

    sig.initSign(privKey);
    sig.update(message);

    return sig.sign();
}

class Utils{
    private static char[] lookup = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    public static void outputValue(String s, byte[] data, int length, PrintStream out, boolean wtf){
        out.print(s+" = ");
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            out.print(lookup[(data[i] >> 4) & 0xF]);
            out.print(lookup[data[i] & 0xF]);
        }
        out.println();
    }
    public static byte[] getBytes(String s){
        byte[] result = new byte[s.length()>>1];
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i*2, i*2+2), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - my mistake on the reversed parameters.  The entire app is included now (with the aberrant debugging code removed).   I suspect the problem is that i need to specify X9.31 padding, and can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, the reversal was my own fault while grabbing at straws.   I suspect the problem is that i need to specify X9.31 padding.   The input for this comes from RSA verification vectors from CAVP.  The come in the form of the following:

Comment: The data comes from a vector file from NIST    The runnable code won't fit in a comment here.

Comment: @user1481471 I have updated my answer because there was a mistake in it. I couldn't find your problem but I've posted working code with a good key pair, you can fill in the message.

Comment: i can do the same if i create my own key, sign and verify.  What i cannot seem to do is get the correct result using Java when i try to use the CAVP vectors.  I will update my question and append a test vector that should Pass (it does when using the same logic implemented in c with openssl).   Thanks

Comment: @user1481471 I have tested the code using the keypair in `SigGen15_186-2.txt` from NIST, [186-2 RSA Test Vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/dss/186-2rsatestvectors.zip). If you send me the link to where you got your sample, I can give it another try.

Comment: @user1481471 Actually I figured out why it wasn't working. Putting a 0x00 byte to the beginning of the keys solves the problem. I think it was the negative `BigInteger` problem. Now both of your samples verify OK.

Comment: @user1481471 By the way, I think `e = 11` for your first example.

Comment: Thanks, but what i am trying to verify is the SigVer15_182-2.txt file.

Comment: @user1481471 Like I said above, your example works fine in the code I posted if you append zeroes to the left of the keys. I suggest you do the same and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

```
BigInteger Nvalue = pubKey.getPublicExponent();
```

N is the key *modulus,* not the public exponent. Your text labels and variable contents don't match up.

Your signature verification problem is probably something else. Do you get an error message, or the `verify()` method simply return `false`?

Comment: The method simply returns false.   I've updated the question to include more code, and two example test vectors.  One which should fail, and on which should pass.    Thanks